# Qual è il "vero" dialetto umbro?

Tags: history

Sono nato e ho sempre vissuto in Umbria e, avendo oggi scoperto questo bel sito, ne approfitto per fare una domanda -spero- interessante.

Come forse saprete in questa piccola regione si parlano un po' di dialetti diversi a seconda della zona: a Perugia hanno il loro (Donca), quello del nord (es: Città di Castello) mi ricorda il romagnolo, mentre nel resto della regione il dialetto è simile al romanesco (ma il nostro è più "grezzo", con apice al confine con le Marche).

Insomma, arrivando al punto, mi appello a qualche studioso di questi argomenti: qual è il dialetto moderno con più influenze risalenti alla lingua degli antichi umbri (quindi parliamo di epoca pre-romana)?

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Comment: Grazie per l'accoglienza!

Comment: Puoi fare esempi di una qualsiasi influenza dell'antica lingua umbra sulle lingue umbre moderne? Wikipedia sostiene che non ve ne sia nessuna (ma Wikipedia può sbagliarsi)

Comment: Sinceramente non ho idea di come fosse la lingua antica, per questo ho fatto questa domanda! :D

Comment: @DenisNardin: [Qui](http://www.tavoleeugubine.it/LE_TAVOLE_DI_GUBBIO/La_ricerca/I_prestiti_linguistici.aspx) si afferma che parole di origine umbro-sabina si trovavano nel latino e si usano ancora in italiano.

Comment: @Charo Hmm.. sarei curioso di sapere quante di queste parole sono effettivamente fluite dall'umbro al latino e quante sono semplicemente state ereditate da entrambe le lingue dal proto-Italico (penso soprattutto a parole come *famiglia* e *casa* che sono tra le più resistenti ai prestiti), ma è probabilmente impossibile saperlo.